# Is a subsemigroup of a Clifford semigroup also a Clifford semigroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

Is a subsemigroup of a Clifford semigroup also a Clifford semigroup? I can prove that the maximal group image of a Clifford semigroup is a Clifford semigroup, but I am not sure whether any subsemigroup is also a Clifford semigroup!!

Comment: Please put tags in the tags section and pick a useful title for the title line.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. The additive group $\mathbb{Z}$ is a Clifford semigroup, but its subsemigroup $\mathbb{N}$ is not even regular.

Comment: What if $S$ is a Clifford semigroup and if we take $S'$  as a subsemilattice of $S$( as we can consider $S$ as a semilattice of groups \cite Howie). Are the groups of $S'$ in this case Clifford semigroups?

Comment: All groups are Clifford semigroups.